# .Net migration not working when I register my repository as a service in Program.cs

Tags: c#, .net, migration

So working on an ecommerce application I created my repository interface, class & model.

Then I registered the repository as a service when I added the migration I go this error:

> An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. Continuing without the application service provider.
>
> Error: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: CoffeeShop.Models.Interfaces.IOrderRepository Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: CoffeeShop.Models.Services.OrderRepository': Unable to resolve service for type 'CoffeeShop.Models.Services.ShoppingCartRepository' while attempting to activate 'CoffeeShop.Models.Services.OrderRepository'.)
>
> Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[CoffeeShop.Data.CoffeeShopDBContext]' while attempting to activate 'CoffeeShop.Data.CoffeeShopDBContext'.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

My other repositories like shopping cart have been working fine. But when I remove the registration in `Program.cs` I don't get any errors:

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>();

//  This line of code below is causing the issue 
builder.Services.AddScoped<IOrderRepository, OrderRepository>();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<CoffeeShopDBContext>(option => option.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("CoffeeShopDbConnection")));
builder.Services.AddScoped<IShoppingCartRepository, ShoppingCartRepository>(s => ShoppingCartRepository.GetCart(s));
```

I've doubled checked that all the required services have been registered and the repository and models are configured correctly.

Here is my repository class:

```
using CoffeeShop.Data;
using CoffeeShop.Models.Interfaces;

namespace CoffeeShop.Models.Services
{
    public class OrderRepository : IOrderRepository
    {
        private CoffeeShopDBContext dBContext;
        private IShoppingCartRepository shopCartRepository;

        public OrderRepository(CoffeeShopDBContext dBContext, ShoppingCartRepository shoppingCartRepository)
        {
            this.dBContext = dBContext; 
            this.shopCartRepository = shoppingCartRepository;   
        }

        public void PlaceOrder(Order order)
        {
           var shoppingCartItems = shopCartRepository.GetShoppingCartItems();
            order.OrderDetails = new List<OrderDetail>(); 

            foreach(var item in shoppingCartItems) 
            {
                var orderDetail = new OrderDetail()
                {
                    Quantity = item.Qty,
                    ProductId = (int)item.Product.Id, 
                    Price = (decimal)item.Product.Price, 
                };

                order.OrderDetails.Add(orderDetail);
            }

            order.OrderPlaced = DateTime.Now;
            order.OrderTotal = shopCartRepository.GetShoppingCartTotal();   

            dBContext.Orders.Add(order);
            dBContext.SaveChanges();    
        }
    }
}
```

I'm new to .NET so any patience and help would be much appreciated

Comment: Its a little strange that you are getting a shopping cart while registering your shopping cart repository service. `builder.Services.AddScoped<IShoppingCartRepository, ShoppingCartRepository>(s => ShoppingCartRepository.GetCart(s))` That just looks wrong.

Comment: Off topic: You should not use a repository inside another repository. This can cause cyclic references if you do not watch out.

Comment: Do you access the database in the constructor of your `ShoppingCartRepository`?

Comment: You are doing a migration and often issue is do to connection string not connecting to database.  found article for troubleshooting Entity Core Migration : https://thedatafarm.com/data-access/no-executable-found-matching-command-dotnet-ef/

Comment: What account are you using to start the service?  A service defaults to starting with a System Account which often doesn't have all the environmental variable to run an app.  Normally you will create a Service Account and then run your service using the service account instead of the default System Account.

Comment: Is this all of your code for Program.cs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe one issue might be that you're registering an interface but the ctor wants the concrete implementation, which it can't resolve.

Try to change the ctor from:

```
public OrderRepository(CoffeeShopDBContext dBContext, ShoppingCartRepository shoppingCartRepository)
```

To:

```
public OrderRepository(CoffeeShopDBContext dBContext, IShoppingCartRepository shoppingCartRepository)
```

For the AddDbContext, try changing this:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<CoffeeShopDBContext>(option => option.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("CoffeeShopDbConnection")));
```

To this:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<CoffeeShopDBContext>(option => option.UseSqlServer("name=ConnectionStrings:CoffeeShopDbConnection"));
```

The reason is that you can't use builder.Configuration until after .Build() has been called.

Answer (score 0):

I want to thank everyone for all the help and advice in the comments and the excellent answer. I'll take it on board.

So it turned out to be something really simple which was instead of `@model ExampleModel` I used `@Model ExampleModel` which is why things broke.

If fixed this and everything worked fine.

It's always helpful to work out things by process of elimination and ensuring there are no syntactic or logical errors I guess.